# If a random variable is uniformly bounded, i.e., $|X_j| \leq C$ for all $j = 1,2,\ldots$, does the fourth moment exist?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I read somewhere that it is trivial to see that if a sequence of random variables are uniformly bounded, i.e., $|X_j| \leq C$ for all $j = 1,2,\ldots$, then $E(X_j^4)$ exists. I am not sure where this result is from, could someone guide me? I can prove it but am not sure if this is the result of some convergence theorem. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In General, if $\left|X\right|$ is bounded by a constant $C>0$, i.e $\left|X\right| \leq C$ a.s,  then
$$
\Bbb E [|X^n|] =\Bbb E [|X|^n] \leq \Bbb E[C^n] =C^n <\infty,
$$
for all $n \in \Bbb N$.
So all moments exist.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need any convergence theorems. If $|X| \le C$, then its pdf $f_X(x)$ it is necessarily zero outside of $[-C,C]$, and $\int_{-C}^C f_X(x) \; dx =1$; i.e. $P( -C \le X \le C)=1$.
$$
|E[X^4]| = \left\vert \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^4 f_X(x) \; dx \right\vert
= \left\vert  \int_{-C}^C x^4 f_X(x) \; dx\right\vert \le  \int_{-C}^C |x|^4 f_X(x) \; dx \le C^4 \int_{-C}^C f_X(x) \; dx = C^4.
$$
and this is finite.

Comment: Can you please share why $[a,b] \subseteq [-C,C]$? Thanks!

Comment: Looking back the $[a,b]$ part isn't needed and I'm just overcomplicating things. Let me know if the update makes sense.

Comment: No need for a PDF, which is fortunate since PDFs often do not exist.

Comment: Thanks @Did I didn't think about that. user321627 you should accept Cettt answer - it is an improvement upon mine.